# Preventing Cross Site scripting attack

Tags: c#, asp.net, scripting, xss

I have been told to resolve the XSS script attack. So here is the Scenario,

See the Images for your understanding
[Image 1](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=4142288416615), [Image 2](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=11142288419011), [Image 3](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1614228842121)

What I want is that any script which is written here should get encoded and should redirect to error page which I have created.

Now, with my current code, the page is redirecting to the Error page when any script is written, But I want that script also to get Encoded.

Please see my code which makes this happens, also let me know where Should I make changes so that it can encode it.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(Regex.IsMatch(txtSearch.Text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 %  +]"))
        {   
            Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            String ClearSpaces = Regex.Replace(txtSearch.Text, @"\s+", " ");
            Response.Redirect("search.aspx?tx=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClearSpaces));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's me again from your other question :)
If you ask this after implementing that other guy's solution, it seems that as I told you, the XSS is not mitigated.
I don't understand what you mean by "any script which is written here should get encoded and should redirect to error page which I have created" - If you redirect to an error page the input of the user is not presented in any way.

As I told you in the other post, if this code that you written here is not a part of search.aspx, than accessing search.aspx directly would bypass this validation.
You should copy this validation to search.aspx and also validate QueryString["tx"], and\or HTMLEncode any usage of QueryString["tx"] at the output of your page.

Comment: I agree with you. for time being i have used that solution. Do let me know the permanent solution and i will test that on my local. Thanks for considering